# Android Java Dagger Inject Problems

Tags: android, dagger

**My AppComponent**

```
 @Singleton
 @Component(modules = {SplashModule.class})
   public interface AppComponent  {
     void inject(SplashActivity splashActivity);//this is inject activity
    
 }
```

**Splash Module**

```
@Module
public class SplashModule {

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   static SplashInteract provideSplashInteract(){
      return new SplashInteract();//instance interact
    };

   @Provides
   @Singleton
    SplashPresenter provideSplashPresenter(SplashInteract splashInteract){
      return new SplashPresenter(splashInteract);//instance SplashPresenter
     };
 }
```

**Splash Presenter**

```
 public class SplashPresenter implements ISplashContract.Presenter {

  ISplashContract.View mView;
 SplashInteract splashInteract;


public SplashPresenter(SplashInteract splashInteract) {
    this.splashInteract =splashInteract;
}

public void bindView(ISplashContract.View mView) {
    this.mView = mView;
}

   @Override
    public void attach() {

    this.mView.startAnimation();//start splash animation
  }

  @Override
   public void start(Activity activity) {
    this.splashInteract.SplashScreenAnimation(activity);// add interact methods
    }
 }
```

**Splash Activity**

```
 public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ISplashContract.View{

 @Inject SplashPresenter splashPresenter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    getAppComponent().inject(this);//call BaseApp DaggerAppComponent 
    splashPresenter.attach();
    splashPresenter.bindView(this);
  }


    @Override
    public void startAnimation() {
    this.splashPresenter.start(this);
   }

 }
```

**Base App**

```
 public class BaseApp  extends Application {

 private  static AppComponent appComponent;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setUp();
  }

   private void setUp() {
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().build();//Call Component in BaseApp
   }

   public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    return appComponent;
   }
}
```

**Hi Everyone**

**I am writing a project, I want to use dagger, but I am inexperienced at this. This code gives a NullPointerException error. I could not find what I am doing wrong.**

**I need help and I will be glad if those who know better than the dagger guide me**

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the exception please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, dagger will not know how to provide splashPresenter, either do a constructor Injection or define in the module how SplashPresenter should be created, and remove SpashPresenter from the Component. The module approach should be like so,

```
@Module
public class SplashModule {

 ISplashContract.View  mView;

   public SplashModule(ISplashContract.View mView) {
    this.mView = mView;//add SplashModule view
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public ISplashContract.View provideSplashPresenter(){
    return mView;//set this view
  }

   @Provides
   static SplashInteract provideSplashInteract(){
    return new SplashInteract();//instance interact 
  };

   @Provides
   SplashPresenter provideSplashPresenter(ISplashContract.View mView, SplashInteract splashInteract){
    return new SplashPresenter(mView, splashInteract);//instance SplashPresenter 
  };

 }
```

And remove inject annotations from SplashPresenter and you will also have to change the signature for its constructor. You can optionally remove Singleton annotation from the code, if the presenter is not supposed to be singleton.

**Updates based on comments**

````
 public class SplashModule {

   @Provides
   static SplashInteract provideSplashInteract(){
    return new SplashInteract();//instance interact 
  };

   @Provides
   SplashPresenter provideSplashPresenter(SplashInteract splashInteract){
    return new SplashPresenter(splashInteract);//instance SplashPresenter 
  };

 }
 public class SplashPresenter implements ISplashContract.Presenter {

   ISplashContract.View mView;
   SplashInteract splashInteract;

  public SplashPresenter(SplashInteract splashInteract) {
    this.splashInteract = splashInteract;
  }

  public void bindView(ISplashContract.View mView) {
    this.mView = mView;
  }

   @Override
    public void attach() {

    this.mView.startAnimation();//start splash animation
  }

  @Override
   public void start(Activity activity) {
    this.splashInteract.SplashScreenAnimation(activity);// add interact methods
    }
 }

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ISplashContract.View{

 @Inject SplashPresenter splashPresenter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    getAppComponent().inject(this);//call BaseApp DaggerAppComponent 
    splashPresenter.bind("the view you want to bind")
    splashPresenter.attach();
  }


    @Override
    public void startAnimation() {
    this.splashPresenter.start(this);
   }

 }```
````

Comment: Mohammed makes this error when I do what you said ---> Cannot have more than one binding method with the same name in a single module

Comment: you should rename this method as it is not providing presenter 
  public ISplashContract.View provideSplashPresenter()

Comment: Now it is telling me to set the splashmodule in BaseApp class. error --movieapp.view.di.SplashModule must be set

Comment: How do I set SplashActivity in BaseApp?

Comment: Your Dagger builder needs to provide SplashModule, that is how Dagger will know how to work with Splsh module, though I do see you need a view in the splash module, my recommendation would to separate that out and make a separate bind method in the presenter to bind views

Comment: Should I use separate module for view?

Comment: dagger is so hard on me

Comment: no, because when you create a component you are starting a dependency tree, you cannot provide another module at the activity level

Comment: Please, you are the science of showing with code I did not understand

Comment: Well, I would recommend using Hilt, but not for production since it is still in alpha I believe

Comment: I put it on my head, I'll play it

Comment: I updated the answer for code, theoretically it should work, if not there may be some syntactical errors

Comment: Should I inject it in presenter to use the interact class?

Comment: you don't have to unless you use constructor injection, in which case you can remove the providesPresenter method, though My personal preference is to avoid constructor injection because it becomes difficult to manage dependencies, the module would be a one-stop shop to know how your dependencies are generated

Comment: I made president but is this giving an error?-->Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.zaurfarrukhzada.movieapp.view.view.activity.splash.ISplashContract$View.startAnimation()' on a null object reference

Comment: splashPresenter.bind("the view you want to bind") is this line not giving you that exception?

Comment: I am assuming you forgot to add that

Comment: No, I did not forget, I wrote like this ->  splashPresenter.bindView(this);

Comment: Seems like your DI portion is working, not sure if the view you are providing in bindView is null, or if attach is being called before you can bind the view, either way that looks like a logical issue

Comment: I changed the lines of the line, it was improved

Comment: splashPresenter.bindView(this);
 splashPresenter.attach();

Comment: Good Luck, I believe Hilt is right around the corner so we no longer have to deal with Dagger boilerplate, things are a lot simpler there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare your `BaseApp` in `AndroidManifest` :

```
<application
        android:name=".fullPathTo.BaseApp"
        ...
```